# Trying to access rails attributes throught habtm relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, attributes, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm a rails newbie and I'm trying to setup a simple habtm for users and roles.
I'm trying to assign a role to a user in my seed file but I always getting this error:

> Can't mass-assign protected attributes: roles

I created the linked table without id like this:

```
create_table :roles_users, :id => false do |t|
  t.references :role, :user
end
```

And my user and role model look like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
  devise :database_authenticatable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :roles_attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :roles, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users

  attr_accessible :name
end
```

When I try to assign a role to a user in my seed file that looks like this:

```
#Create a role
role = Role.find_or_create_by_name 'admin'

#Create test user
user = User.find_or_create_by_email 'niels@work.be'
user.update_attributes! password: 'testme', password_confirmation: 'testme', roles: role
```

the rake command while always stop and complain that it can't mass-assign protected attributes ?

Any body a clue what I'm doing wrong and guide me in the right direction?
Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Seems to me it is a security hole if you allow roles to be mass-assigned.

Answer (score 0):

```
roles: [role]
attr_accessible :roles #if required

role_ids: [role.id]
attr_accessible :role_ids #if required
```